# How can I align such equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

[image]

This is my code, but I'm failing to achieve the same result as in the picture.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta&=\frac{2M}{2n+1}(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+...)&< \\
&<\frac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}(1+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+...)&=\frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)}< \frac{2M}{24n^3}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Your code does not reproduce exactly the contents of the formula: the first parenthesis begins with $\dfrac13$, not $1+\dfrac13$.

Answer (score 1):

From question is not clear, how you like to have aligned your equation, so, I made two version. The first use `array environment` and align equation in two places (quite unusual), the second use `align`  and equation are aligned only in one plaece.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for shoving only an equation
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{preview}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\[
    \begin{array}{rll}
\Delta  & = \frac{2M}{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
                            +\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsm\right)
            & < \\[1ex]
        & < \frac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
                            +\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsm\Bigr)
            & = \frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)} < \frac{2M}{24n^3}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{align*}
\Delta  & = \frac{2M}{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
                            +\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsm\right) \\
        & < \frac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}\biggl(1+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
                            +\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsm\biggr)
            = \frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)} < \frac{2M}{24n^3}
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

I also change your elipsis with ones which are provided by `amsmath` (in ma MWE called by `mathools`)

**Edit:** As you can see, the fractions are not the same in both cases. In array environment are not in `displaystyle` mode. To have them equal as they are in `align` environment, than you need to replace `\frac{...}{...}` with `\dfrac{...}{...}`.

Now you can select a solution, which you more like.

**Edit:** Barbara Beeton noted me, that I would consider the size parenthesis too. So I correct my MWE so, that the first line of cases use `\left(` and `\right)` parenthesis, the second one `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` (the first case) and `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` respectively. By this I try to give comparison between automatic "stretchable" and "fixed" size of parenthesis. Many people prefer to use fixed size.

Comment: May be better suited the `alignat` environment?

Comment: Thanks, but the second "<" sign needs to be directly below the first "=". It doesn't seem to work using your code

Comment: @Thomas, now I see, that the first sign in the second line should be `<`, not `\le`, this is easy to correct. Other is not clear from your question. Can I conclude, that you like to have aligned equations only in one place, at `=` after `\Delta`?

Comment: The attached picture shows precisely what I need except \le. Is there any way to avoid the gap between the right bracket and equal sign in second row?

Comment: Yes, it is. See my upgrade answer.

Comment: @Thomas How do you plan to remove that space if you still want both lines to be aligned? If you just want to align at one point (at the first equal with the less than below) then you can do it with `\begin{equation}\begin{split}\Delta &= … \\ &< … \end{split}\end{equation}`.

Comment: Both of them need to be aligned.. Not sure if there's any way to achieve the same as in the picture I attached?@Zarko Can you share the code? How did you align these two?

Comment: @Thomas In the picture they are aligned because the part inbetween happens to be of the same width in both rows. So, if it isn't the same width then you should decide whether you want to align *leaving some gap* or not to align.

Comment: Understood, I'll go with leaving the gap then

Comment: @Zarko -- you want to use larger parentheses around the fractions.  `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` might be a good candidate pair.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, yes, till to now I was focused only to aligning of equation. When compare both solution, I saw discrepancy in fraction and obviously overlooked parenthesis. I will upgrade my answer and pointed out this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce the picture, but I don't advise to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spread}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi][s]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\Delta 
&= \frac{2M}{2n+1}
   \biggl(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
           +\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsb
   \biggr)
   &&< \\
&\Spread{2}{
   {<{}}\frac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}
     \biggl(1+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
             +\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsb
     \biggr)
    }
    &&= \frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)} < \frac{2M}{24n^3}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above code uses a number of nasty tricks I'm not going to explain. I'd rather explain why you shouldn't use that format:

1. there's no need to repeat the < sign at the end of the first line;
2. the entire construction is unbalanced.

I'd much prefer three lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Delta
&= \frac{2M}{2n+1}
   \biggl(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
           +\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsb
   \biggr) \\
&< \frac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}
   \biggl(1+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
           +\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsb
   \biggr) \\
&= \frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)} < \frac{2M}{24n^3}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To closely mimic the image, you can still do this (observe the font and italic symbol `\mathit{\Delta}`, etc):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathit{\Delta} &= \dfrac{2M}{2n+1}\left (\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsc \right ) &< \\
&< \dfrac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}\left (1+\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsc \right ) &= \frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)} < \frac{2M}{24n^3}
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, if you needed something more professional, you would go with `mtpro2`, for example. Your example, then, could be written in a better way like this (similar to egreg's proposition):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Delta
&= \frac{2M}{2n+1}
   \Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
           +\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsb
   \Bigr) \\
&< \frac{2M}{3(2n+1)^3}
   \Bigl(1+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
           +\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}+\dotsb
   \Bigr) \\
&= \frac{2M}{3\cdot(2n+1)\cdot 2n \cdot (2n+2)} < \frac{2M}{24n^3}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]